# Prevent credentials that do not match those in the database from logging in

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got this register/login script that's going really well (I'm new to php).

I've run into a problem whereby any credentials can log in and create a session, the code isn't looking at what is inputted then checking the database to see if they're correct, I get this error message.

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Game\login.php on line 25

Now I've done a little research and I found a question (on this very site) that states the query I'm giving is returning a boolean rather than a result. Here's the code

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where password='$password' AND    username='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Usually a correct answer gives me the information to fix my problem and not have to post here, but I have no idea how to rectify this :(

Comment: You should NEVER insert variables directly into your SQL query. They must be escaped first. Even better: Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query` will return a boolean, most likely `false`, because of a failure with your query. Best to use `mysqli_error` to find out why it's not working, without showing any more code we won't be able to even guess.

Comment: The mysqli_error gave me an informative error that allowed me to make the changes and it's now working!! Thanks so much! I will use that more often, saves making more questions for you to answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Well you have no result from the query you made, so the line with $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query); will give you 0 rows, just test it if its greater them 0 like;

```
if ($rows > 0) {
    //do the magic :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that Your query isreturning something or not.if it is not returning something then just handle it in other way. just assume this is as following way

```
if($query === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); //  error handling
}
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```